# Tem alguma maneira de eu alterar dados de diferentes colunas mas deixando isso em uma só variável?

Tags: php, mysql

Resumindo.... Usar vários updates em uma só variavel

Tipo:
    $query = 'update.....; update.........'

Tem algum modo?

Comment: Acho melhor você tentar formular melhor sua pergunta, pelo menos **eu** não entendi o que você esta tentando fazer,

Comment: Eu entendi a sua pergunta (não foi fácil) mas pra formular a resposta, teria que saber qual driver tu usa: mysqli? PDO?

Comment: Desculpem-me..... Eu uso mysqli

Comment: Não seria de diferentes linhas?

Comment: Qual o `sgbd` que utiliza?

Comment: Talvez ajude: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6821184/how-do-you-do-multiple-sql-statments-in-one-mysql-query

Answer (score 2):

Você deve estar usando o `mysql_query`, porém aceita apenas uma query. Tente utilizar o [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php). Um exemplo;

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

/* verifica conexão */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";

/* executa a sua multi query */
if ($mysqli->multi_query($query)) {
    do {
        /* Faz print separado do resultado de cada query */
        if ($result = $mysqli->store_result()) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_row()) {
                printf("%s\n", $row[0]);
            }
            $result->free();
        }
        /* separa cada resultado por traços */
        if ($mysqli->more_results()) {
            printf("-----------------\n");
        }
    } while ($mysqli->next_result());
}

/* fecha conexão */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```